# Value of jmh GC profiler results

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, benchmarking

To avoid most well-known pitfalls of benchmarking on the JVM, I use jmh (java microbenchmarking harness). Also, I do understand that garbage collection can distort benchmark results.

Now I wonder how expressive the results of jmh with `-prof gc` are. Does jmh take special action to make the results meaningful?

Other questions in my mind are:

- What if garbage collection did not happen during the measurement?
- Will garbage collection be forced by jmh if profiling gc?
- What is the effect of each benchmark being run in a separate JVM / java process to the gc profiling?

Answer (score 3):

> Also, I do understand that garbage collection can distort benchmark results.

It does not really *distort* results. If your code creates garbage then a GC cycle is part of the performance costs that your algorithm incurs. You're just paying it in an amortized manner instead of per-invocation. Of course it is up to the benchmark-writer to ensure that the iteration and warmup counts are set to number large enough that you get a meaningful sample, so if you wish to also measure the impact of GC you need to run your benchmark long enough for it to let the GC ergonomics reach a steady state.

And of course a micro-benchmark is just that, it is not a whole-application benchmark. And since GC costs often depend on more than allocation rate (e.g. live set size is another factor) those results should be interpreted with caution.